# How do I read a list from a textarea with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to read in a list of words separated by spaces from a textbox with Javascript. This will eventually be in a website.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This should pretty much do it:***

```
<textarea id="foo">some text here</textarea>

<script>
    var element = document.getElementById('foo');
    var wordlist = element.value.split(' ');
    // wordlist now contains 3 values: 'some', 'text' and 'here'
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A more accurate way to do this is to use regular expressions to strip extra spaces first, and than use @Aron's method, otherwise, if you have something like "a b     c     d  e" you will get an array with a lot of empty string elements, which I'm sure you don't want

Therefore, you should use:

```
<textarea id="foo">
    this is some   very     bad
    formatted text         a      
</textarea>

<script>
   var str = document.getElementById('foo').value;
   str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s$/g);
   var words = str.split(' ');
   // words will have exactly 7 items (the 7 words in the textarea)
</script>
```

The first .replace() function replaces all consecutive spaces with 1 space and the second one trims the whitespace from the start and the end of the string, making it ideal for word parsing :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **splitting** by whitespaces, you can also try **matching** sequences of non-whitespace characters.

```
var words = document.getElementById('foo').value.match(/\S+/g);
```

Problems with the splitting method is that when there are leading or trailing whitespaces, you will get an empty element for them. For example, `" hello world "` would give you `["", "hello", "world", ""]`.

You may strip the whitespaces before and after the text, but there is another problem: When the string is empty. For example, splitting `""` will give you `[""]`.

Instead of finding what we don't want and split it, I think it is better to look for what we want.